# Como plotar o modelo estimado da regressão logística

Tags: r, regressão, plot, ggplot2

Suponha que eu tenha os dados abaixo, aplique neles uma regressão logística e queira visualizar a função estimada que retorna a probabilidade.

```
#Simula os dados
nobs<-100
beta0=-10
beta1=0.006
saldo=runif(nobs,1300,2300)
p_x <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * saldo) / (1 + exp(beta0 + beta1 * saldo))
y <- rbinom(n=length(saldo), size=1, prob=p_x)
data <- data.frame(saldo, p_x, y)
#Regressão
default.glm = glm(y~saldo, data=data,family=binomial) 
summary(default.glm)
```

O código abaixo não está plotando adequadamente a função y=probabilidade prevista e x= saldo.

```
plot(saldo,y)
lines(data$saldo, default.glm$fitted, type="l", col="red")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com a função `plot` base, você teria que ordenar os dados antes:

```
plot(saldo,y)
lines(data$saldo[order(data$saldo)], default.glm$fitted[order(data$saldo)], type="l", col="red")
```

[image: Gráfico com a linha de ajuste]

Com o `gpplot2` você não precisa ordenar, só plotar x contra o ajuste.

```
 library(ggplot2)
    grafico <- ggplot(data, aes(x=saldo, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
                   geom_line(aes(x=saldo, y=default.glm$fitted), col="red")
    grafico
```

[image: Gráfico com a linha de ajuste ggplot2]

Ou você pode mandar o `ggplot` fazer a regressão com o `geom_smooth`, vai dar na mesma:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=saldo, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
                  geom_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", col="red", se=F)
```